# How to compare objects with expanding amount of data?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, architecture

Given a class like:

```
class State {
    bool IsLessThan(State);
    int data;
};
```

The `State::IsLessThan(State)` method can simply compare `data` in each class according to some logic. However let's say the data within `State` is expected to change throughout development and hold different predefined types of data groups which the client decides to add to the state. One way to implement this is:

```
class State {
    void Add(StateData);
    bool IsLessThan(State);
    Set<StateData> data;
};
```

Where any derived class of `StateData` can be thought of as a `struct` with some data. Assume that if a `State` does not contain a type of `StateData`, it has an instance created with default values. Every time a new type of `StateData` is added to the program, the logic and therefore code in `State::IsLessThan(State)` will need to be changed.

Assume that the main concern here is architecture extensibility. Can this be improved? Am I missing a better solution?

Comment: Google for "semaphore"

Comment: That's not really relevant here as it's all on a single thread.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of hints that this is in c++. Mind confirming that in the tags?

Comment: It is C++, I probably should have mentioned that

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase your question, you have a class where instances must be able to compare themselves to other instances of the class, but where the contained data can vary and be extended in initially-unpredictable ways. You are concerned that the comparison requirement will be difficult to cleanly solve due to the data variation, and you hope to solve this by having the class contain an extensible `StateData` class.

Unfortunately, this is just moving the problem from one place to another. Sure, the `StateData` class can cleanly encapsulate the varying data, but then you have to figure out how to compare differing data structures, and you're once again staring at the original problem.

Unless you can create general rules for comparing the varying data you will be in a world of hurt once the data structures proliferate. To me, this is a strong indication that your design is flawed; either you should put clear constraints on the data to be contained, or the whole premise should be rethought and the data reorganized in some cleaner, more regular fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Complex objects are usually compared by their members. Define a "less than" comparison for Set and StateData and compare containing objects delegating to their members. 
Do not try to implement comparison of objects with arbitrary structure, this usually causes associativity breakdown.

Comparisons of sets are usually poorly defined, you will want to be strict about it.
For example, you could say that a Set is less than another Set if all of its members are less than any of members in another Set.

To generalize, if something does not have a well-defined structure, implement operation as part of its stable interface. Client code would not need to know it's structure at all.

Answer (score 0):

> How to compare objects with expanding amount of data?

Make sure there is a clearly defined order between the various types (and values) of data.

> Assume that the main concern here is architecture extensibility.

To solve the problem of implementing `bool IsLessThan(State);`, you must solve these separate problems:

- how can you tell if one instance of StateData is less than another instance of StateData, when the instances have different types
- how can you tell if one instance of SetData is less than another when then have the same type
- what does it mean for two State instances to compare less than one anohter, based on the contents of a set.

Neither of these has trivial answers, as the answer depends on the problem domain. It also seems (to me) like you are trying to solve the wrong (x-y) problem (which usually means you need more design / refactoring, or just to take a step back and reexamine what you are doing.

You are already talking about comparing objects of different types (specializations of StateData). Does that make semantical sense for all specializations of StateData? (that is, if one of your StateData has an image inside and the other a calendar date, can you really say that one is "bigger" than the other?

> Can this be improved? Am I missing a better solution?

Are you sure you are solving the correct problem?